# Method of characteristics - integral surface formation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, surfaces

On page 2 of [this PDF from Standord](http://web.stanford.edu/class/math220a/handouts/firstorder.pdf), which describes the Method of Characteristics for first-order PDEs, it is written at the end of the page:

> "In doing so, we see that $z(x,t)$ is constant along the lines $x-at=x_0$. That is, $z(x,t)=f(x-at)$."

I don't see one thing here: when they write that $z(x,t)$ is constant along $x-at$, do they mean that, since $x-at=x_0$, where $x_0$ is a constant, and $z(s) = k$, where $k$ is also some constant, we can express $z(x,t) = k$ in terms of $x-at=k$? Moreover, what does $f(x-at)$ do to $z(x,t)$? That is, I don't understand how this function is exactly justified.

Would appreciate a clarification.

Comment: As you have noted the method gives $z(x,t) = k$ along lines $x - at = x_0$. The constant $k$ is in principle different for different values of $x_0$ so it's really a function of $x_0$ so we should write $k = k(x_0)$ and since $x_0 = x-at$ we have $z(x,t) = k(x_0) = k(x-at)$. The function $k(\cdot)$ is the same as the function $f(\cdot)$.

Comment: @Winther, why does $k$ need to depend on $x_0$?

Comment: What we show when we apply the method is that the function is constant along any given line $x-at = x_0$ it does not say that the value $z$ takes along one such line needs to be equal to the value it takes along another line. If this value was the same for all lines then $z(x,t)$ would be a constant for all $x,t$.